# Dual basis problem on the space of polynomials $\mathbb{R}_{1}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Problem goes as follows:

Let $\mathbb{R}_{1}[x]$  be the linear space of polynomials of degree $\leq 1$.
Define the covectors $f_{1}, f_{2} \in (\mathbb{R}_{1}[x])^{*}$ (dual space), as:

$$ f_{1}(p(x)) = \int_{0}^{1} p(x) \,dx $$

$$ f_{2}(p(x)) = \int_{0}^{2} p(x) \,dx $$.

Determine the basis of $\mathbb{R}_{1}[x]$ whose dual basis is $\{ f_{1}, f_{2} \}$.

My solution:

Let $\{v_{1}, v_{2}\}$ be the basis dual to $\{ f_{1}, f_{2} \}$.

Given the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}_{1}[x]$,  $\{ e_{1} = 1, e_{2} = x \}$, I can form a matrix $f_{i}(e_{j})$, evaluating, I determine it to be:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dfrac{1}{2} \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
 $$

The inverse of this matrix is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{4}{3} & -\dfrac{1}{3} \\
-\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So the columns of this matrix are the coefficients of the polynomials I looking for.
Hence,

$v_{1} = \dfrac{4}{3} - \dfrac{2}{3}x, v_{2} = -\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{2}{3}x$

Is this correct?

Comment: $f_2(v_1)=4/3$, so, this is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $f_1(a+bx)=a+\tfrac1{2}b$ and $f_2(a+bx)=2(a+b)$, therefore $f_1(a+bx)=1$ and $f_1(a+bx)=0$ if and only if $a=2$ and $b=-2$. By the other hand $f_1(a+bx)=0$ and $f_2(a+bx)=1$ if and only if $b=1$ and $a=-\tfrac1{2}$, so the dual basis is $\{2-2x,-\tfrac1{2}+x\}$.